# Undo IDatabaseTester setDataSet()

Tags: java, junit, hsqldb

I have two independent JUnit tests that use [IDatabaseTester](http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/dbunit/IDatabaseTester.html) to load schema, then data from an XML.

When run individually, all goes well. But when run in succession, the second JUnit test fails because "the TABLE name already exists".

I have tracked it to the fact that the HSQLDB database is attempted to be loaded *twice*. Of course it would fail in the second time.

I looked at the [IDatabaseTester](http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/dbunit/IDatabaseTester.html) definition and while there are methods to set the database, I could not find one to "unset" it.

What is the proper way to unload it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering own question, in case it helps someone else:

```
import org.apache.ddlutils.Platform;
import java.sql.Connection;
import org.apache.ddlutils.model.Database;

Platform platform = PlatformFactory.createNewPlatformInstance(HSQLDB_JDBC_DRIVER, HSQLDB_JDBC_URL);
Database database = jdbcModelReader.getDatabase(hsqldbConnection, null);
platform.dropTables(database, true);
```